# Subsetting data in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark

I'm new to programming in Spark, and the StackOverFlow community. Trying to get a subset of data using Spark in the Cloudera QuickStart VM. In the attached snapshot you will see an output of 20 records using the code:

```
channel_views.take(20)
```

Here, `channel_views` is an RDD that contains several hundred records. I'm trying to subset only those specific records that contain the word 'XYZ' and the corresponding numeric values. How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`RDD.filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.filter):

```
channel_views.filter(lambda x: "XYZ" == x[1])  # Exact matches
```

or

```
channel_views.filter(lambda x: "XYZ" in x[1])  # XYZ in the value
```

Comment: zero323: Thank you for your response. I tried using your first command in the Spark command line, and it does not provide a list of records containing the exact word "XYZ". Instead the output says "PythonRDD[44] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:43". Not sure what this means.

Comment: Thank you, zero323! Your solution and resources helped! Forgive my ignorance on this subject - I'm new (1 week old) to the field of Spark, as well as the stackoverflow community.